# C# Type and class issue

Tags: c#, types

I have the following Method:

```
void Register<T> where T : class {
   _myList.Add(typeof(T))
}
```

Where _myList is a `List<Type>`.

I now want to call a generic class for each Type:

```
 cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("MyTestQueue", ec => {
  _myList.ForEach(t => ec.ConfigureConsumer<GenericConsumer<typeof(T)>>(context);
});
```

Any idea how I can do that ?

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates, blog posts, whatever you can think of. Please try to do a bit of research next time. As a bit extra help, you can (and should) search like this in the future: `c# generic from type site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: It's not the same issue, I've udpated the question

Comment: Can you edit your question with more details, please? The linked questions demonstrate the use of `MakeGenericType` and `MakeGenericMethod`, which are all you need to solve this problem.

Comment: @BenD It's still the exact same issue. You need to call `ec.ConfigureConsumer<T>` through Reflection

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving the `Type` you could save a delegate to `MyGeneric<T>`, like:

```
List<Action> _myList = new List<Action>();

void Register<T>() where T : class
{
    _myList.Add(() => MyGeneric<T>());
}

void MyGeneric<T>()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Running MyGeneric<{typeof(T)}>");
}
    
void Run()
{
    foreach (var del in _myList)
    {
        del();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Register<string>();
Register<int[]>();

Run();
```

Result:

```
Running MyGeneric<System.String>
Running MyGeneric<System.Int32[]>
```

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect my problem more precisely.